# Correct process to merge fork changes into GitHub

Tags: eclipse, git, github, egit

I am new to GitHub. I don't know the correct process to merge my changes with the upstream. I followed following steps using EGit (I like to use it because I find it simple). Please help me.

1. On GitHub I created a fork.
2. For my fork I cloned a repository in Eclipse and imported respective projects.
3. In remotes, I added one more for the main project say Upstream(from where I forked) on GitHub.
4. I added some changes into my local repository.

How can I do the following part? -
Now in the meantime other people added some changes to the upstream. Now I want to integrate my changes(in the fork I created) to the latest changes(upstream) using EGit and push it to my repository and send a pull request.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

1. create another remote corresponding to *your* fork in Eclipse
2. publish (`push`) your changes into your fork repo on github
3. create a merge request from the web interface in the original github repo, pointing to your changes on github

Comment: Thank you I did create a merge request but there are merge conflicts. So I think before I send pull request I have to merge code. That is where I am stuck and using Egit it doesn't merge

Comment: I'd suggest to `rebase` your changes over the actual state of the upstream repository. In this case you solve all possible conflicts locally (e.g. re-edit the files and create a new, conflictless change) and then repeat the procedure: push new commits to your fork, create/update the pull request

Answer (score 0):

There is the procedure, how I do it.

**GitHub browser UI**

1. delete your fork with too much mess, if exists - this is in your **Settings** -> **Danger Zone**, the button is in upper menu bar in the root of fork
2. fork for you a new one on the foreign page, where I have access
3. open newly created fork and copy URI to the clipboard

**Git perspective in Eclipse**

3. create clone of your fork in my GUI Eclipse
4. Create a new branch in local branches and activate it
5. Import project from working tree in Eclipse as general project from Git perspective to actual workspace
6. do changes, integrate your important files to the general project (add to index etc.)
7. commit, push

**GitHub browser UI**

8. create Pull request from your fork directly from actual branch (recommended) or after merge in master branch

[image]

Notice, that in the picture is merge branch selected. In our real case is better to use the name, which is more descriptive.